# Map API/Layer that may be used in pages requiring login

Tags: google-maps, mapping, gis

I'm developing an application with a feature that allows users to mark places on a map (events, locations etc.). I'm not allowed to use the basic google maps api because it requires pages that implement the maps to be publicly available. Does anyone know of any alternative with rich layers (including Europe, Asia, etc.) that can be used freely on non-public pages?

---

This question is wrong but I'm leaving it anyway in case anyone else tries to ask it. The problem is I misinterpreted the TOS on google maps API which google have clarified. You can use it in pages that require login as long as you don't charge your users.

There are opensource and free alternatives too which may be more flexible but are much harder and of lower quality as programming APIs. OpenLayers (OenstreetMaps is based on it) is the best and most popular one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)?

Comment: Yes, it's based on OpenLayers which is pretty flexible but not as good JS api.

Answer (score 0):

For a private page you might well find it more cost-effective to license some proper maps. Might not be that expensive for a limited userbase.

Do you actually need maps as such, how about some of the other geolocation sources like gazetteers, etc. List of some sources [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Potential_Datasources).